# Which names (besides for Voldemort) do the movies pronounce wrong?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison, jk-rowling, pronunciation

JK Rowling has said the Voldemort is pronounced Volde**mor** (with a slient **t**). In the movies they always pronounce it Volde**mort**.

### Are there any other names which the movies pronounce incorrectly?

Comment: Harry Potter = on topic. +1

Comment: I've heard her, herself, pronounce the 'T' multiple times (and there are tons of clips of her enunciating the 'T'). Not to mention, she was pretty heavily involved in the production of the films and never thought to correct the name of the 2nd most important character in the series. I think the current pronunciation has more to do with her wanting to be trendy and staying relevant than it has to do with 'right' and 'wrong' pronunciation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "differently," not "wrong?"

Comment: @RogueJedi Title was assuming that Rowling>movies.

Comment: If you're Asking a Question like that, why not put your Post through a spell-checker, at least?

"Which names (besides for Voldemort) do the movies pronounce wrong?" is itself wrong, twice.

"Which names (beside Voldemort) do the movies pronounce wrongly?" would seem to be what you meant.

How is it anything but hypocritical or lazy to include several mistakes in a Question about other people's mistakes?

Answer (score 7):

With what little I know about the French language, I know that Beauxbatons should be bo-ba-to (French).

Despite failing at French, they got the Celtic names pretty well. I was actually surprised when Hermione and Seamus were pronounced correctly.

Comment: To clarify: Hermione is from Greek. Seamus is from Celtic. (You probably already know this. But your answer makes it sound like Hermione is also from Celtic.)

Comment: Both Hermione and Seamus are perfectly ordinary and not particularly uncommon names in English, though, so it would be most surprising if they'd got them _wrong_.

Answer (score 5):

If you count spells, there's also **Accio**.

The letter C in English is pronounced like K when coming before an A, O, U, or another consonant, and like S when preceding an E, I, or Y. (Examples: *cart*, *coming*, *curt*, *preceding*, *civil*, *fancy*, *includes*.) This includes when two C's are adjacent, as in the word *accent* - pronounced *aksent* because the first C comes before a consonant while the second precedes an E. Therefore the word ***Accio* should be pronounced *aksio***.

This is borne out by Stephen Fry's audiobook versions of the Harry Potter books, for which he consulted heavily with JK Rowling, and in which *Accio* is indeed pronounced *Aksio*. But in the films it's pronounced *Akkio*, which sounds quite different.

Comment: +1 I do count spells, despite the question asking for names

Comment: @Accio_Answer That username of yours is perfect for this answer!

Comment: But accio is Latinate, and neither classical nor Medieval Latin have a sibilant C.

Comment: Is there any official source on spells being pronounced as if they were English words? Most of them look Latin-like.

Comment: @OrangeDog In that case, Crucio should be pronounced *krukio* - but doesn't that sound weird?

Comment: @lfurini Not sure, but there's the audiobooks for a start. See also my comment to OrangeDog above. I'll look for any recording of JK Rowling saying "accio".

Comment: Not as weird as *krusio* sounds to me.

Comment: `C` pronounced `k` is one possible Latin pronounciation, but another one (called _Ecclesiastical pronunciation_) has `C` pronounced as `tʃ` (= as in the English word "such").

Comment: Dammit, the existence of [Accio Quote](http://www.accio-quote.org/) makes it well-nigh impossible to Google for JK Rowling interviews mentioning the word *accio*!

Comment: Spells are fine. Any invented words (e.g. dementors) are also fine.

Comment: @lfurini In Ecclesiastical Latin (which is basically just Mediaeval Latin with a bit of an accent), however, a geminate c remains a geminate, regardless of the following sound; and an o is just a simple /o/, not a diphthong as in English. So _accio_ should there be not /ˡaktʃoʊ/, but /ˡatʃːo/, pretty much exactly how it would be pronounced in Italian.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That is exactly how I always read it! :-) "accio" = /ˡatʃːo/ and "crucio" = /ˡkrutʃio/