# What is the correct pronunciation of 'Accio'?

Tags: harry-potter

For out-of-universe English speakers, what would be the correct pronunciation of "Accio"?

Has J.K. Rowling ever been heard to say it or commented on the correct phonetic pronunciation?

The question arises because at least three, possibly authoritative sources indicate three different pronunciations.

1) Stephen Fry — Narrator UK (audio book): **ax-see-o**

2) Jim Dale — Narrator US (audio book): **ass-see-o**

3) Films — (example: Harry in *Goblet of Fire*): **ack-e-o**

Comment: [Latin nerds argue until the death of the sun]

Comment: I'd go with Stephen Fry's take on this one. See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118438/98028) who mentions he talked a lot with JKR, even if there are no sources. Also, from what I remember of my Latin classes, _ax-see-o_ sounds about right (but those were some time ago, ahah).

Comment: @Jenayah - Fry's interpretation is my guy reaction as most authoritative as well - even though I am more familiar w/ Jim Dale's reading. But - one can assume that JKR was involved in the film and would have said something if the movie's interpretation was flatly incorrect - so it's a puzzle

Comment: Pure speculation, but if more people expect to here _ack-e-o_, or the producers thought it sounded better, they may have had a word over the pronunciation. However, by the fourth movie they should be past "will we make money with that thing" thoughts. Maybe some actor pronounced it wrongly and went on with it...

Comment: Classical or church latin? If classical latin I'd go with the film pronunciation as c's are always hard. (see e.g. https://www.wikihow.com/Pronounce-Latin). If Church Latin atchio is probably closer (http://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780190246778/student/church/).

Comment: @IanBush - irrelevant imo (unless there is a known consensus/fact that JKR uses one over the other). Basically, what does JKR hear in her head / say when she rights / says it herself :)

Comment: @NKCampbell - JKR never corrected the films when they mispronounced Voldemort, so I don't think you can assume she'd correct them on Accio.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Latin nerds can argue all they want, but they need to remember that JKR’s spells are not Latin. They’re JKR-ish, often (though not always: _Alohomora_, _Avada Kedavra_, etc.) based on some smattering of Latin stock, but basically just made up. How a string of letters would be pronounced in Latin is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, if only the irrelevance of an argument about Latin were ever an obstacle to nerds' arguing...

Comment: @ibid what? Mispronounced Voldemort? How are you supposed to say it?

Comment: @marcellothearcane - Voldemore. The "t" is silent. (It's French.)

Comment: Ahh this makes more sense now. I grew up listening to the audiobooks on repeat and it always said ah-see-o. I was so confused when the movies pronounced it different. Good to know, another mystery solved :)

Comment: @ibid of course! Thanks for ruining the films for me now! :D

Comment: @ibid According to [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/mort), with the “t” is also an acceptable pronunciation for native French speakers.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor - Rowling has said several times in interviews that the correct pronunciation of the character is with a silent T.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor - according to my understanding of French pronunciation, that is only true if the word following it begins with a vowel.

Comment: I believe the correct pronunciation is 'Get over here' in a deep, guttural growl.

Comment: Why, please? Are you hoping to cast a spell, or what?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - did you read the entire question? There are three different ways of pronouncing it, depending on which media you consume. (similar to, but not asked because of - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256144/are-there-any-in-book-clues-that-the-t-in-voldemort-is-silent-and-why-did-the)

Comment: @NKCampbell Thanks and I meant every word. For a "correct" pronounciation, you'd need to ask JKR herself.

For why there are clearly more than three choices, you could ask anyone interested in languages in general, and Romance tongues in particular.

For a reason to Ask such a Question again, why? Are you hoping to cast a spell, or what?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - do you ask everyone asking questions on this site why they are asking? Somebody asking about how lightsabers work can expect to get acosted about trying to build one? Be nice. I was curious because I've heard three difference ways of saying the word. Good grief...

Comment: @NKCampbell Not everyone, no. When a Question seems largely pointless, of course. Since like everyone else, I forced to give at least enough time to read the Question before evaluating it, you be kind! You're welcome to deny rights or duties are attached to using public forums. I think anyone Posting a Question has a duty to be sure it's a worthy Question, and all readers who don't agree, a right to whinge - if that's how you'd like to think of it.  


FYI there are several other potential ways of pronouncing "accio"  - see Buzz, for two.

Comment: @NKCampbell I left out, there are two kinds of language; Latin & its Romance children lie in the sorry camp, from your view.

English is a Germanic tongue yet "either" can sound "ee-" or "eye-ther". Who doubts that?

Pure German admits no choices; only "eye-ther". Suggesting "ee-" proves a failure to understand.

Rowling seems to base magic on pig-Romance Latin, yet even pure Latin was famously mis-spoken by huge numbers of Users birth, schooling, upbringing or experience notwithstanding.

Failing JK's dictat, no "correct" sounding of "accio" could ever be. Who doubts that?

Answer (score 9):

Most spells in Harry Potter are in "dog Latin,"  a Latinate cant of the kind that gives us real-world phrases such as *hocus pocus*.  With this in mind, I suspect that precision in pronunciation is probably not a critical issue in using these spells; any of the standard Latin pronunciation systems would thus probably be acceptable.

*Accio* is a very ordinary Latin word.  The classical pronunciation would have been AHK-ee-oh.  Church Latin (which evolved largely in parallel with the pronunciation of Italian) would give AHX-ee-oh.  Either would probably work fine.

Comment: I've updated the question to add the detail that this question is intended to address out of universe pronunciation. As indicated in the question, each medium pronounces it consistently differently in said medium and the spell 'works' in universe, so the question doesn't address in-universe pronunciation (ie - Wingardum Levio-*sah*)

Comment: (ps, I'm not the downvoter, so I'm giving you an upvote since you answered prior to my clarification)

Comment: The Italianate pronunciation would use the "ch" sound of "change" (held for a longer period of time, because it is a double consonant). The pronunciation with the "x" /ks/ sound of "axe" comes from the English or French traditional pronunciation, not the Italian pronunciation of Latin.

Comment: I always read it as if the root word were "access" (which, after looking up its etymology, has a different Latin origin) - I didn't even consider that it was its own legitimate Latin word.  Given that the word itself ostensibly means "summon", that's probably the best guess for how she chose it, and probably what guided the filmmakers in the pronunciation. I always hated the "AHK-ee-oh" pronunciation, but I guess I'll have to get over that now :)

Comment: In-universe, at least, there are points that make it clear that correct pronunciation is quite important. Remember the stuff about Wingardium Levios-A?

Answer (score 1):

In *Fantastic Beasts* Leta says **ack-e-o** and as that's the case in HP films as well, I would consider this the correct pronunciation. Both movies were supervised by JKR, if they had questions on spell pronunciations they probably would ask her (unlike audio books narrators).

Comment: ["*JKR never corrected the films when they mispronounced Voldemort, so I don't think you can assume she'd correct them on Accio*"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192022/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-accio/198852#comment525523_192022)

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, I saw that, but first: Voldemort pronunciations differs not as much as *akkeo* vs *axseeo* - maybe wizards themselves pronounce it differently, not a big deal. Can't be the case with a spell, as pronunciation is crucial here. And second: actors might not have questions about Voldemort and just pronounced it as they saw it, but *accio* doesn't seem obvious at all - I would ask for help there if I were an actor.

Comment: I think we've seen that the movies and the books don't necessarily follow the same canon

Comment: @Valorum Agree. But from all other evidences, repeated *ackeo* in the movies seems to be the best we have. Unless JKR comment on it publicly herself. I would also add that in cyrillic languages *accio* also transliterated as *akseeo* or even *aktsio*, but again the people who translated it probably just guessed. Film creators are the only ones who were the closest to the original source if they'd bother to ask.

Comment: I'd still like to find a clip of her reading from one of her books

Answer (score 0):

It means acquire. Therefore the correct pronunciation is ack-e-o. If it meant asquire then ass-e-o would be correct, however, as that is not a word, it clearly isn't pronounced that way.

Comment: I can't say I agree with this answer. I don't have any example in mind right now, but some English words which were inspired by Latin words didn't have the same pronunciation either.